# AJAX/LocalStorage : Is it possible to pass a JS variable to PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, request

I was wondering, what'd be the best way to store a shopping cart?
I thought about storing products ID's in localstorage/sessionstorage and then use AJAX to retrieve the products from the server.
The only problem is that I don't know how to pass the items from the localstorage to PHP...
I'm guessing it's probably not possible directly, and I thought about a form though I have no idea how to implent it...
The idea is that when a user clicks "Add to cart" the item id and quantity is added to the localstorage, and when a user views his cart, the item details (image, name, price...) are being retreived from the database.
I'm probably going to use this tutorial
  http://verido.dk/index.php/ressourcer/artikler/loading-and-saving-data-dynamically-using-php-jquery-and-mysql/

I could as well give up on local storage and go with sessions and database but I'd really like to give users that dynamic web experience.

Another possible way I just came up with is to use URLs like file.php?prodid=......, although URLs like this may get way too long.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For long request why not use .post ?

Comment: To expand on what **kritya** said, you should be able to do exactly what you are describing; you just need to submit an AJAX request to your PHP script using `.post` that contains the shopping cart contents. Then the response to that request would need to be the item details and whatever else you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'You must remember that Server-Side (PHP) code is read before it converts the code to browser-side code.  JavaScript is manipulated browser-side...

So one-dimensionally, you cannot pass JavaScript to PHP.

However...

With Ajax and in your case I suggest JSON you can send JavaScript data to a PHP page and bring the response back to your JavaScript methods.  I think this will suit your needs.  I can provide a simple example if you want.

//--example below:

JavaScript:

```
//Ajax Method
function processAjax(queryString, processDiv, responseDiv) {

responseDiv.innerHTML = '';
var myAjax;
try {
    // Modern Browsers-->
    myAjax =new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e) {
    // antique ie browsers-->
    try {
        myAjax =new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            myAjax =new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            // Something went wrong
            document.getElementById('processDiv').innerHTML="";
            alert("Your browser malfunctioned!  Please try again. Consider installing a modern browser if the problem persists.");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
myAjax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (myAjax.readyState == 4) {
        var ajaxResponse = myAjax.responseText;
                responseDiv.innerHTML = ajaxResponse;
        processDiv.innerHTML = "";

                    //NOTE: HERE IS WHERE AJAX IS FINISHED, SO IF YOU WANT TO DO SOMETHING ELSE HERE YOU CAN!
                    //POST PROCESSING----->
                    // IE: alert('I am finished processing now!');
                    // or call another function:
                    // anotherFunction();

            } else {
        processDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/loadingicon.gif" alt="processing....." />';
    }
}
myAjax.open("GET", queryString, true);
myAjax.send(null);

}


function sendStorage() {

   var helloVar = 'Hello, I am passed to PHP #1';
   var worldVar = 'I am the second value passed to PHP!';
   var processId = 'process_div';
   var resultId = 'result_div';
   var queryString = 'http://www.mysite.com/process.php?hello=' + helloVar + '&world=' + worldVar;

   processAjax(queryString, processId, resultId);

}
```

Now for some HTML:

```
<div id="content">
       <div id="process_div"> This is where processing will occur </div>
       <div id="result_div"> This is where my response will display </div>
</div>
```

Now for a process.php (NOTE: FOR SECURITY, I STRONGLY SUGGEST YOU DON'T REVEAL A SERVER-SIDE PROCESSING PAGE IN YOUR JAVASCRIPT)

```
<?php

  //init
  $hello = '';
  $world = '';
  $errors = 0;

  //set
  //Security note: never trust a URL request.. you should clean all $_GET, $_REQUEST, AND $_POST with the PHP htmlspecialchars() method (take a look at php.net for that)
  (isset($_GET['hello'])) ? $hello = $_GET['hello'] : $errors++;
  (isset($_GET['world'])) ? $world = $_GET['world'] : $errors++;

  //process
  if($errors > 0) {
      echo 'Errors Detected! Missing querystring get data!';
  } else {
      echo '<p>Hello received: ' . $hello . '</p>';
      echo '<p>World received: ' . $world . '</p>';
      //now we can process $hello and $world server side!
  }
```

?>

Important: you should really look into learning some JSON and $_POST requests as they are more secure, faster and you can easily manipulate returned data.  I suggest looking at a library like jquery for simplified examples.

I have not tested this code, but it should work.. Let me know if you have questions or this does not answer your question.

Glad to help!

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I'm looking for. Please provide me with an example. I'd mainly like to know how to send the data with AJAX effectively. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.. give me a few minutes as I'm in the middle of something.

Comment: Thanks for the example! Looks really good. Just a little question, as for not-revealing the process page, what options are there? Should I use a "mediator" page or something? Thanks again for taking your time to write this example!

Comment: That gets complicated.. What most folks do they use a router.  add an extra querystring param like action  mysite.com?action=process_cart   then with php if(isset($_GET['action'])) { require_once(path_to_mysite . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'actions_directory' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_GET['action'] . '.php); }  Then place your code in that action file.. but that is pretty complicated to explain here.

Answer (score 2):

Use AJAX to send data to the server (GET or POST) and store these values in a session variable or cookie on the server

Comment: Wouldn't that just ruin the whole idea of using localstorage? lol

Comment: local storage could be used for long time storage and PHP session variables could mirror these values on the server side temporarily

Answer (score 1):

You can use your local/session storage data and populate some hidden inputs, then submit the respective form in an ajax request. To make things cleaner you can use one hidden input and set it's value into a JSON object created from your storage data.

Comment: Great idea actually, I will look into it some more! Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

No, javascript runs on the client, php runs on the server.

Comment: I know, and that's exactly the problem. My question is basically if there's a way to overcome this problem, because many people suggest to use localstorage for shopping carts.

Comment: While that is true, it does not prevent the kind of behavior he is wanting.